# How do I compute a sum with a for-loop and add up the results?

Tags: python, computation

I have the following code:

```
aapl = [10, 154.12]
goog = [ 2, 812.56]
tsla = [12, 342.12]
fb   = [18, 209.0]

portfolio = [ aapl, goog, tsla, fb ]
market = [ 198.84, 1217.93, 267.66, 179.06 ]
print(portfolio[3][0])

# pnl=((market[0]-portfolio[0][1])*portfolio[0][0])+((market[1]-portfolio[1][1])*portfolio[1][0])+((market[2]-portfolio[2][1])*portfolio[2][0])+((market[3]-portfolio[3][1])*portfolio[3][0])
# print(pnl)


total_pnl = 0

for n in range(0, 3):
    pnl=(market[n]-portfolio[n][1])*portfolio[n][0]
    total_pnl += pnl

print(total_pnl)
```

The quoted out code returns the correct result: -174,5.
The for-loop is the same equation, but looped over the different list items, yet it returns 364,42.
I'm assuming this is because of the adding up of the results.

Please help me find my error, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range(0, 3)` is the mistake, it returns only 0, 1, 2.

But market has 4 items.
So use `range(0, 4)` or `range(0, len(market))`

Answer (score 1):

`range(0, 3)` is the mistake:

It returns the list `[0, 1, 2]`, so the last number you pass in is not used as an index. Try `range(0, 4)` or `range(0, len(market))`